# Can I access a struct passed into a template generically?

Tags: c++, templates, struct

As per the title, this is what I am looking to do. Basically I am looking to load in structures from files, but support every kind of structure, so I am attempting to do it in a template. This is my first time using templates really so excuse my ignorance!

I want to be able to do something like:

```
template<class T> T ConfigLoader::LoadStructFromFile(T a)
{
    int noOfThingsInStruct;
    noOfThingsInStruct = a[1];
    return a;
}
```

Is this at all possible? 
My function does sorting of the string loaded in from files etc but thought I would leave that part out.
I want to be able to get this value to use it to loop and give the struct the correct number of values it is looking for.

Comment: Side note: wouldn't `things_count` be more clear than `noOfThingsInStruct`? I see a lot of people who think long names are more descriptive, so it's better. No, they just make you blind.

Comment: Try Boost serialization. It is a good idea to have used something before designing it. E.g. you wouldn't want to be a passenger in a plane designed by someone who had never been in a plane.

Comment: Yes probably, however it was just quickly to post up a question.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I am programming this to specifically avoid using boost :).

Comment: OK, but (I still recommend that you) try it first.

Comment: Yeah, I should have tried it in more detail, I simply wrote a[1] earlier and it didn't throw an error, So I assumed it was legal, however I did not check which value it held nor if I could make something equal it. My bad on that part!

Answer (score 1):

So you want to dynamically figure out what members and methods are in a struct? Similar to, say, what you can do in Javascript in runtime, but in compile time? No, you can't. However, you can make a template policy and base this function on that.

Comment: Sorry, I do not quite understand what you mean by that?
As in the second part.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure. Theoretically for a concrete instantiation, you know sizes of all fields. I would not be surprised if some variadic templates or boost magic was able to do figure out what fields of what types are there. The problem might be with the fact, that compiler can reorganize order of members and memory layout.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple answer:** impossible.

**Long answer:** still no.

**Detour:**

- you can use something based on [type traits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/). Create a template class `numberOfElements<typename T>` and overload it for every `struct` you need with a value you expect. Then, use it in your `LoadStructFromFile`, since you know `T`.
- You can also use [SFINAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence) to test for some function that'll return the number of elements in a struct. If a given class/struct implements it, just use it to get the number of members. If not - assume there's only 1 member (or whatever you wish).

Comment: Looks like I am gonna have to redesign how I do it then, minus the template. 
I not only need access to the first element, but then each one after that in order to put the value from the text file into it. Thanks for the answer.